# Simplifying a sed expression to save a portion of a line from a file into a variable (bash)

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a bash script which will isolate a portion of a string and save it to a variable in a bash script.  Assuming `$INSTALL_INFO` is a variable with the file I wish to pull data from, I'm doing something like this.

```
 BOOST=`cat $INSTALL_INFO | grep 'BOOST:' | sed 's/BOOST://g' | sed 's/^[ \t]*//'`
```

In this case, boost is the keyword I'm looking for. The format for the items in the file is:

```
<possible whitespace><exact title><indeterminate whitespace><data I want><possible whitespace>
```

there has got to be a cleaner way of doing this with one sed command, but I was unable to figure anything out.

Comment: It would help to see some exact input lines and some exact expected output lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to approach this is to use `sed -n`, which will only print lines that match the expression(s), and one expression that describes the entire line, keeping only the parts you want.

```
BOOST=$(sed -n 's/^.*BOOST:[ \t]*\([^ \t]*\).*$/\1/p' $INSTALL_INFO)
```

The trailing `/p` tells `sed` to print the line (after the replacement has been performed).

If your "data I want" can itself contain whitespace, it gets a bit trickier. You have to modify the expression to "chew up" the whitespace at the end of the line. I would switch to Perl to be able to use its "reluctant" modifier (a `?` after a repetition operator):

```
BOOST=$(perl -ne 'print if s/^.*BOOST:\s*(.*?)\s*$/\1/' install_info.txt)
```

Of course, with Perl you can just print the part that matches instead of modifying the line:

```
BOOST=$(perl -ne 'print $1 if /BOOST:\s*(.*?)\s*$/' install_info.txt)
```

Comment: note that the OP had a `grep` that limited the input for `sed`...

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yup, an unnecessary one.